# Error Code 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'AIN'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set datafields with two others datafields and I have the error's message stayed above.

The following query is :

```
UPDATE mydb_jobersplace.t_jp_localisation SET
    T_JP_Localisation_NumDptEtDpt = T_JP_Localisation_NumDpt + ' - ' + T_JP_Localisation_Dpt;

T_JP_Localisation_NumDptEtDpt - Varchar(90)
T_JP_Localisation_NumDpt - VarChar(3)
T_JP_Localisation_Dpt - VarChar (45)
```

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: Why are you trying to add strings (VARCHAR)?

Comment: Try [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
UPDATE mydb_jobersplace.t_jp_localisation SET
    T_JP_Localisation_NumDptEtDpt = CONCAT_WS(' - ', T_JP_Localisation_NumDpt, T_JP_Localisation_Dpt);
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)'s the documentation for `CONCAT_WS` function, it will skip the `null` values as well.